# Best way to display trees?

Tags: tree

I have to port an old java program to a web app (using Angular) for my company. We have this huge tree structured database, and it's displayed in a standard, old-fashion look:

[image: tree Display]

As the data are huge, it's really annoying to navigate the database in this way.
(clients have been complaining :S )
What is the best way to display such data ?

Comment: What you want to do after you navigate / select particular item is also important to know before we design.

Comment: Just a standard treeview control the lets you collapse and expand the branches?    Does it expand / collapse now?

Comment: Yes it does expand/collapse. Also, when we select a leaf, we can update its path, and some attributs.

Answer (score 2):

There is plenty of idea here https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery[image]

http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

If you want to try their code  go here:  http://runnable.com/ and
https://vida.io/explore

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the structure of the database should either present the most efficient way of searching through the information and/or presenting the information. You mentioned here that the presentation method is not optimal, but without knowing the underlying structure and the relationship between the elements it would be difficult to propose a better solution. You did mention that it was a tree structure, but perhaps the content has outgrown that original structure and something else might be more appropriate?

But looking from the perspective of an abstract problem/solution, there are some possible workarounds:

1. Change the presentation of the structure, since it is too cumbersome to display or interact in a meaningful way.
2. Change the hierarchy and structure of the database, and the presentation will match the change.
3. Reduce the scope of the information you are showing at one time, so you don't have to present the entire data structure in its entirety.